# sql join on range giving double row for single record

Tags: sql, sqlite

I needed to join three tables Result, ResultITems and GradeScale. When i do, i get double or two of the same row. I tried Creating the records in sqlfiddle but i get a different correct result. The schema i used in creating the tables in my local sqlite db is exactly the same, which is shown here.

The result table

```
CREATE TABLE Result ( 
    ID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    SubjectID INTEGER REFERENCES Subjects ( ID ) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    SessionID INT     REFERENCES Sessions ( ID ),
    TermID    INT     REFERENCES terms ( ID ),
    ClassID   INTEGER REFERENCES Classes ( ID )
);
```

The resultItems table

```
CREATE TABLE ResultItems ( 
    StudentID INTEGER,
    ResultID  INTEGER REFERENCES Result ( ID ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Total     DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) 
);
```

And the gradescale table

```
CREATE TABLE gradeScale
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    minscore tinyint NOT NULL,
 maxscore tinyint NOT NULL,
 grade char(1) NOT NULL,
    ClassCatID INTEGER 
);
```

now when i execute this query below, i et double row for each record in the ResultItems table

```
Select ri.studentid, ri.Total,g.grade
From ResultItems ri

left join GradeScale g
ON ( ri.total >= g.minscore AND ri.total <= g.maxscore )

left join Result r on r.id=ri.resultid

 WHERE r.sessionid = 4 
       AND
       r.termid = 1 
       AND
       r.classid = 9
 ORDER BY grade ASC;
```

Please see the picture below to see what i mean
![enter image description here][1]

and here is the sql fibble which i created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ffb42/1

why am i getting double rows in the output when i execute in my local db?

Comment: You have duplicates in one of the tables, in all likelihood.

Comment: Why do you do a LEFT JOIN and also have outer table conditions on the WHERE clause? That makes it a regular inner join... (BTW, is results a good and describing table name? Results of what?!?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I dont understand what you mean

Comment: @jarlh I am doing a left join on a table and an outer join on another. This si to filter the result from the query. The table names are Result, ResultItems and GradeScale

Comment: @Smith, I see what you mean. But putting conditions on the outer table in the WHERE clause makes the outer join to perform just like an inner join. (Non-matching rows from the left side will never be returned!)

Comment: The point is i get a different thin in sqlfiddle.net and my local db, why? And any suggestions on how i can get the desired output

Comment: Because your data is different? Please, see how your duplicates look like, and then look for the data that originates that rows in all related tables, and you'll yourself get the answer: if you get duplicated rows, taht's because you have duplicated data in some tables.

Comment: there's no duplicate data in my table. And i used a sample result because the database has over 1000 rows in each table. The problem seems to come from the GradeScale join. when i remove it, i get single rows for as i am suppose to just as in the sqlfiddle

Comment: @JotaBe I backed-up my database, cleared it and used the sample data from the sql fiddle, see the result in the edit, just what i complained about

Comment: Please, track down the data in the different tables that can yield for example, the first row. You'll see that at least, in one of the tables, there are duplicated matching rows. The easiest way is to make a `select *`, so that you can see what the offending data is, and where it comes from (perhaps you're missing a join condition or a filter, believe me!)

Comment: @JotaBe I notice where the problem is coming from, posted the wrong schema (dizziness i guess) , i will post the real schema. Can you please help look at the new sqlfiddle

Comment: @JotaBe your comment helped me track down the answer, can you post them so i mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @JotaBet's help, i was able to trace the error to the GradeScale table wihci had double entries for each grade letter for each class group.

So i rewrote the sql to take notice of that

```
left join GradeScale g
ON ( AND c.classcatid =  g.classcatid (ri.total >= g.minscore AND ri.total <= g.maxscore) )
```